# How to add two numbers from different lists that are included in lists of lists in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to obtain a list with the sum of all the first numbers if the are having the second element equal and if they are in the same list of lists. How can I do that?

List items:

```py
[[[98.5, 0], [3.5, 1], [0.73, 4], [98.5, 0], [3.5, 1], [0.73, 4],[9,2], [[14.88, 1], [1.3, 3], [14.88, 1], [1.3, 3]]]
```

How can I obtain the list:

List items:

```py
[[[197, 0], [7, 1], [1,46, 4],[9,2]], [[29,76, 1], [2,6, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [[[98.5, 0], [3.5, 1], [0.73, 4], [98.5, 0], [3.5, 1], [0.73, 4], [9, 2]],
        [[14.88, 1], [1.3, 3], [14.88, 1], [1.3, 3]]]


def sum_group(l):
    """Sum inner list by group"""
    counts = defaultdict(float)

    for v, group in l:
        counts[group] += v

    return [[v, k] for k, v in counts.items()]


result = [sum_group(l) for l in lst]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[[197.0, 0], [7.0, 1], [1.46, 4], [9.0, 2]], [[29.76, 1], [2.6, 3]]]
```

The idea is to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group and sum the inner list. This is done by the `sum_group` function.

Comment: Thaank you! And if I want to make the multiplication I only change counts[group] = counts[group] * v?

Comment: Not only that you have to change the default value of the defaultdict, something like: `counts = defaultdict(lambda: 1.0)`